# Complex integral $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ over a contour.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am to integrate $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ over a contour $C_{1}$ such that it resembles $\infty$ and is postively oriented and inside it there is $z=-i$ and $z=i$ is not contained by it.

I am not given the equation of the $C_{1}$. However, is using Cauchy integration formula the right way?

Comment: what do you mean by "it resembles $\infty$"?

Comment: A figure-8 type path that hits the origin, probably.

Comment: Exactly. But it doesn't have to hit the origin.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the theorems that state the conditions under which the choice of contour doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the Cauchy integration formula is the right idea. Important detail: the orientation of $C_1$. Specifically, the loop than contains  $-i$ is clockwise or counterclockwise?

Comment: It is counterclockwise.